# phonegap android status bar notification example

Tags: cordova

I am quite new with phonegap and I have found this example of status bar notification:

http://manijshrestha.wordpress.com/2012/11/23/implementing-android-status-bar-notification-in-phonegapcordova-app/#comment-397

https://github.com/manijshrestha/PhonegapStatusNotificationDemo

I am using https://build.phonegap.com service in order to build and deploy it in my android device.

But the when i install the app on my device, and in the index.html I click on the notify button nothing happens..

What are exactly the files that I have to upload? only

the www ziped folder?

I have tried several ways and i can’t not get it to work.. please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure Phonegap build support your plugin in the first place. If it's not, you have to build/compile it yourself. It's not difficult to setup.

Comment: Ok thanks, I think it is not supported so I will try to build it by myself.

Comment: I made it work. I have downloaded the latest cordova version I created a project and I have runned ./cordova/build