# Phone gap App notifications on background

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

Ok, i have an app on android running in the background that can listen to my server, is it possible to show a notification on the status bar when something happens on the app? 
i would like a solution in phonegap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the phonegap statusbar notification plugin to implement this feature.

See here:

https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/StatusBarNotification

Comment: can this plugin be used with phonegap build?

Comment: what versio of phonegap you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Check this : [Phonegap Notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774771/phonegap-android-status-bar-notification-example) and [Phonegap Notifications](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html)

Hope this helps.